# How to use QueryString on UserId defined in aspNet_membership?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-membership, querystringparameter

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASPNETDBConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [JobList] WHERE [UserId] = @UserId">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="c0502e35-ecb1-4c5c-b9a4-f681ac4dc274"  Name="UserId" QueryStringField="UserId" Type="Object" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How to use QueryString on UserId defined in aspNet_membership?

My order table has a foreign key of UserId from aspNet_membership, uniqueidentifier.

I tried above by walking through the configure datasource,even specify a single UserId not working

Comment: Describe more what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Outside from code-behind, you can access query string like this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString
```